# Coordinates for molecules except cartesian and zmatrix

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

Every program in theoretical chemistry that I know uses different ways of writing their input. The same holds true for writing the geometry of the molecules of interest. But they can all be reduced to be either cartesian or zmatrix representation. 
Intuitively these two are the natural answers to the problem of specifying a molecule geometry.

Nevertheless:
Are there programs in use that use anything different e.g. zylindrical, or elliptical coordinates?

Comment: What would be the point? It is natural to use cylindrical coordinates in a problem with cylindrical symmetry - that is, in a linear molecule. But such molecules look perfectly fine in the standard cartesian form as well, so why bother. Come to think of it, there are certain molecules (fullerenes, for instance) which might look kinda natural in _spherical_ coordinates, but again, this is a field too narrow to justify the necessary adaptations.

Comment: Besides Cartesian and z-matrix, some codes specify coordinates in reciprocal space, particularly for solid-state codes (i.e., you give the full unit cell in fractional XYZ).

Comment: That's not quite what we call reciprocal space. Good point, though.

Comment: I had the same thoughts as @IvanNeretin in mind. But since I write a python module myself for converting between xyz and zmat files. I wanted to make sure that I did not forget another important kind of coordinate specifications.

(I know that babel exists but it is too inaccurate for my purpose)

Comment: @mcocdawc If you think Babel is "inaccurate," I'd really like to get an e-mail explaining your problems.

Comment: @Geoff Hutchison Thank you for your interest. I made yesterday a bug report on openbabel on GitHub regarding this problem (same user name).